# Button doesn't make value appear in textBox

Tags: c#

I want 2 *textBoxes* to show numbers after I press a button, but when I press a button, one textBox shows number in it and the second doesn't.

```
    private void Calculating(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox6.Text != "")
        {
           rutr = Double.Parse(textBox6.Text);
           rutd = rutr * 2;            
           textBox7.Text = (rutd).ToString();
           textBox8.Text = (3 / 4 * pi * rutr * rutr * rutr).ToString();
        }
    }
```

The `textBox8` doesn't show correct number.

Comment: `3 / 4` is `0` - *integer division*

Comment: By *"doesn't show number"*, do you mean it stays **blank** (`""`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very cause of the misbehavior is *integer division*: `3 / 4 == 0` should be

```
// The formula seems to be a volume of a sphere: 3/4 * Pi * r**3 
// It's a physical world, that's why 3.0 - double, not 3M - decimal 
textBox8.Text = (3.0 / 4.0 * pi * rutr * rutr * rutr).ToString();
```

please, notice *floating point* `3.0` value instead of *integer* `3`. Another suggestion is to use `double.TryParse`: if we can parse user input (`textBox6.Text`) then do it and compute

```
private void Calculating(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  double rutr = 0.0;

  // If we can parse textBox6.Text into double rutr  
  if (double.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out rutr)) {
    rutd = rutr * 2;            
    textBox7.Text = (rutd).ToString();
    textBox8.Text = (3.0 / 4.0 * pi * rutr * rutr * rutr).ToString(); 
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Technically, it's *possible* to produce *blank* (`""`) in the `textBox8`, see comments below (it's an interesting problem itself). Here's the code

```
    using System.Globalization;

    ...

    CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo);

    // The idea: double.NaN will be displayed as blank 
    ci.NumberFormat.NaNSymbol = "";   

    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;  

    double pi = Math.Sqrt(-1); // pi is double.NaN - imaginary unit 

    ...

    // 0 * NaN * rutr * rutr * rutr == NaN which is printed as empty string
    textBox8.Text = (3 / 4 * pi * rutr * rutr * rutr).ToString();
```

Here we exploit the fact that, `0 * double.NaN == double.NaN`. However, I don't believe in this kind of error

Comment: It should display 0 inside his textbox, no ?

Comment: @Florian: Yes, `3/4 == 0` and `0 * ... == 0`

Comment: Yes, but he says it doesn't show number from what OP says, I think he is saying it doesn't show *any* number which is weird

Comment: @Florian: I can see *clear* error - `3/4` and *vague* description - "second [TextBox] doesn't [show number]". I doubt that `textBox8.Text` is blank: `textBox7.Text` is OK that's why `rutr` is OK, there's a tiny possibility of `NaN` or `Inf` in which I don't believe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a suffix to tell the compiler that the numeric literals are not treated as int.

```
textBox8.Text = (3M / 4M * pi * rutr * rutr * rutr).ToString();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal

Here is a list of possible suffixes:

F:  float
D:  double
U:  uint
L:  long
UL: ulong
M:  decimal

Comment: When `pi` (is it `3.14159...`?) mentioned the formula seems to be from *physical* (not *financial*) world, that's why I suggest using `double`, not  `decimal`: `1d / 4d ...`

Comment: `U`,  `L`, `UL` are all *wrong choices* in the context - *integer division*... Any integer types should not be used. `D` (recommended), `F` (possible) and `M` (in which I don't believe)